# Manage Files in folder and subfolder, like copy your files in your subolder choice

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I need help, I'm trying to create a folder explorer in apex class and visualforce, it's when I want to copy a file in the folder, I can chose the folder or the sub-folder where I want to put my file in salesforce.

I tri this code bellow, but I have an error

```
enter public class selectFolder {
    public List md{get;set;}
    public selectFolder(ApexPages.StandardController Account) 
    {
        md = new List();
        md =  [Select Id,Name,(Select Id,name,(Select id, name from ContentFolderMember) 
        From Folder__c)From ContentFolderMember];
         List documents = [SELECT Id, FolderId, Folder.Name FROM Document 
        WHERE Folder.Name like 'ourLogo%' LIMIT 1];    
      } 
}
```

The error I have is this "

```
Select Id,Name,(Select Id,name,(Select id
          ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:11
No such column 'Name' on entity 'ContentFolderMember'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I did some research and I fine some topic talk about ContentDocuments, ContentFolder or ContentDocumentLinks, but I have no idea how it's work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going two children deep, which I don't think feasible in salesforce. Instead, have one more loop

Comment: Thanks Ysr Shk! How I can use a loop in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no name on content folder member. There is a content parentfolderid which links to the content folder